# Firebase limit users to one session across any device

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created an app for iPhone and I am now in the process of creating an Android version.

My question/issue is, now that I am creating the Android app, I am able to be logged in with the same account in both my iPhone and Android devices for any particular registered user.

Is there a way that would detect if I am logged in to my Firebase user account via my iPhone and then I simultaneously log into that same account with my Android device, it logs the user out from the iPhone device and vise versa.

In essence I want any particular user account to be accessible on one device and no user should be able to access a single account across two different devices.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve the issue?